# how to download databases using WFDB Package

Tags: python

I'm using command prompt to download MIT-BIH database using WFDB packag and I can't download it.

```
import wfdb

import os 

wfdb.dl_database('mitdb', os.getcwd())
```

Comment: This may be more suitable for a bug report than a question here. The only piece of variation you could have done wrong is the parameter `mitdb`. Please, also fix the formatting of your question, which is probably not intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the WiFi and I just connected to another one. Using command prompt just write the code below.

```
                #step 1

python

                #step 2

import wfdb    #if you don't have wfdb package, you can install using (pip install wfdb)

                #step 3

import os

               #step 4

wfdb.io.get_dbs()  #it will list the databases

               #step 5

wfdb.get_record_list('mitdb')  #I have chosen MIT-BIH database and it it will display the content 

               #setp 6

wfdb.io.dl_database('mitdb', r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\MIT-DATA', records='all', annotators='all', keep_subdirs=True, overwrite=False)
```

## the last step will download the data at C:\Users\User\Desktop\MIT-DATA